# Сравнение значений через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, сравнение

Нужна функция, которая проверяет наличие товара из существующих данных это
цвет, размер и количество
Размер:

```
<input class='radio' data-id='2' type="radio" name="option" id="radio" />
<input class='radio' data-id='3' type="radio" name="option" id="radio" />
```

Цвет и кол-во

```
<input type='radio' id="color" name='color' data-color='#fff'  data-id='2=20;3=25'>
<input type='radio' id="color" name='color' data-color='#000'  data-id='2=15;3=20'>
```

Помогите реализовать эту задумку

Comment: Что-то не очень понятен вопрос, какие данные и с чем сравнивать?

Comment: Нужно чтобы когда был нажат `radio button name='option'` он искал совпадения среди `radio button name='color'` т.е `data-id` у размера и `data-id` у цвета

Comment: @AziretKadykeev надо чтоб исходя из data-id вывелось число 20 в первом случае? как сопоставление происходит, что это за 2=20  и 3=25 ? Каков результат быть должен ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Для набора радиокнопок Name должен быть одинаковым, а id - разным. Иначе не будет нормально выбираться одно значение из нескольких.
2. Вместо data-id у набора радиокнопок "option" лучше прописать `value="2"`, `value="3"`, etc.
3. Если я правильно понимаю, то, когда выбрана, например, кнопка "option" с data-id="2", то скрипт должен пройтись по всем кнопкам из набора "color" и получить для них значения из data-id, соответствующие "2". Тогда вам надо: а) пройтись по всем кнопкам из набора "color" в цикле; б) распарсить содержимое атрибута data-id и извлечь оттуда значение после "2=". При этом парсер желательно написать нормальный, который не перепутает "2=" c "12=", например.

Ну а если по-хорошему, то запихивать все данные в атрибут радиокнопки не надо. Лучше сложите их в объект и обратитесь к значениям свойств.